# How can I tokenise file data store it in an array in C?

Tags: c, file-io

Suppose I had a nxn grid of doubles stored in plain text, columns separated by a single space, rows separated by line breaks, for example:

```
1.01 2.22 6.10
-22.10 -15.0 1.0
2.3 -4.4 5.5
```

All I know is the numbers will be doubles, the program must parse nxn doubles (i.e a square matrix) into a 2-d array, but will not know the value of n in advance. If there are nxm numbers, then the program can just exit.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the lines, use `strtok(s, " \t")` to tokenize them, then call `strtod` on the results and store them. Add sanity checks to ensure that what you got is an *n* × *n* matrix.

Better yet, use [`strsep`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) instead of `strtok` if your platform has it.

Alternatively, call `scanf` *n* × *n* times and check its return value each time and finally check whether the file you're reading from is at EOF.

Comment: It's worth noting that `strtok` modifies the input string.

Comment: @Chris: yes, which is why I just added `strsep` and `scanf` to the answer as alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I'm not quite able to get this to work. I'm quite new to C and terrible at parsing files, could you possibly write me an example of how to store them while checking for newline and EOF markers?